# how is c useful in game development

Tags: c++, c

I know that C++ is the king in game development especially in the AAA market can anyone tell my how is C helpful I am a Computer Science student in my first year and are they any aspects of C i have to learn in depth? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

C is a subset of C++.

C is small and lean - a manageable subset of C++.

C++ on the other hand is **huge** and can be very confusing, with many questionable features and design decisions. C++ standard is gigantic.

There are quite a few notable industry figures who prefer using C.
Majority of professionals use a small and very conservative subset of C++.

My suggestion - **learn how to use C thoroughly** before jumping in with C++11.

There are too many features in C++ that look harmless on the surface, but once you start relying on them they blow in your face - **exploding compile times**, **indecipherable template error messages** - just to name a few.

Comment: This all seems like dubious advice to me. C is not a clean subset of C++. Whether or not learning C before C++ is advisable is also up in the air and highly depends on what you're going to use C++ for.

Comment: "C is a subset of C++" you're looking at it the wrong way. C++ is built on C. The original name given to it by Stroustrup was "C with classes".

Comment: "but once you start relying on them they blow in your face - exploding compile times, indecipherable template error messages" This is very subjective. You can't base a language recommendation on that.

Comment: Compile times are NOT subjective. They are very measurable. C++ compiler is slower by an order of magnitude, that's very slow. That's why there's PIMPL idiom, unity builds and precompiled headers. Including and using *simple* and basic features of the standart library - things like STL containers will increase the compile times dramatically. When writing C++ code not only you might think about it's run-time performance, you inevitably end up thinking (and experiencing) it's compile performance.

Comment: Within the context of this question, calling C a subset of C++ seems very appropriate. C is the foundation of C++. As far as learning C++ goes, you basically end up learning the vast majority of C by doing it anyway. Whether you start full on with C++11 or C is up to preference. I suggest learning C in isolation first to get a better understanding of the language.

Comment: wow this seems to be turning into a code war i just want simple advise